# Access 2007, why is my subform header and footer not visible in form view?

Tags: ms-access-2007

Embarrassingly, I think I am missing something rather simple here but I just can't seem to figure this out.  I'd would like a calculated field to appear in the subform header or footer, but I can't even get it visible.

I checked the property sheet settings of the subform and it clearly states: "Form Header--visible. Display When--always".

Appreciate any help in this unnecessarily frustrating matter.

Answer (score 4):

When you right click on the detail, make sure you've selected Form Header/Footer, not Page Header/Footer

[image]

Not OP's issue, but this might help other newbs like myself.

Comment: Thank you. That was it for me as well. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have selected a suitable default view, such as single or continuous form.

[image: form view]

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was going to be something quite easy.  Although, not very intuitive I must say.  Appreciate the quick reply.  Cheers.